# Efficient way of storing large data set in phpMyAdmin SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a large list of exercises that I am currently storing in a SQL table with a unique index value (int) in one column and the exercise name in the other column. I am trying to determine an efficient way of storing sets of exercises as workouts.

As of now, I have two ideas in mind but am not sure what the most efficient (both from a storage and a speed standpoint). These are the ideas I am considering:

**Solution 1** Create a new table that has a column for every exercise that would have a 1 or 0 depending on whether or not it was within a workout. The workout would be an index column, with a unique int id.

**Solution 2** Create a new table that has a the index column representing the unique workouts. A second column that has an array of the numbers that would correspond to the set of workouts. What I prefer about this option is that it would allow me to preserve the order of exercises within the workout.

While I currently only have a list of ~800 exercises and ~400 workouts making **(1)** an array of size 800 x 400 whereas **(2)** would be 400 x 2. However, with the option to create new workout (lets just say that the exercise list will be fixed) table **(1)** would grow significantly faster.

Does anyone have suggestions as to how to minimize size and maintain speed in such a context?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database, it's only a GUI for MySQL. MySQL is your SQL database.

Comment: Table for `set` with `id` and `set name`; table for `setexercises` with `id`, `setId` and `exerciseId` (and possibly an `orderId`)

Answer (score 0):

I like #2 but you could also, if you wanted a more robust solution, have 3 tables:

1. exercises
2. workouts
3. workout_exercises

In addition, I generally would not store the exercises per work out as an array. It would be difficult to use sql to search for a specific exercise within that field, eg:

What workouts contain exercise XYZ?

Your table sizes are actually tiny.  When you have 10,000 records or 100,000 records you can start to think about size issues.